How can I find out how many cases a lawyer has won/lost?
This lawyer in question was unbelievable in every sense of the word.
I don't believe he could be trusted.

If they are so unbelieveable, they surely warrant a Wikipedia entry. Otherwise this needs at least a jurisdiction: typically the Bar association knows if a lawyer is a lawyer or is good.

@Trish The Bar Association or state supreme court will know if a lawyer is a lawyer, but will provide almost no input regarding whether a lawyer is good (apart from a public disciplinary record).

"Court" is not a fair game where the better "player" wins. A statistic like that would mean nothing.

In the united-states, you generally can't find this information.
Most lawyers are licensed to practice in many courts, perhaps in many states, and perhaps in several countries. There is no practical way of finding how many cases a lawyer has even had in all the possible jurisdictions, let alone how many he has won.
Beyond that, there's the more fundamental question of what it means for a lawyer to "win" a case.
If a lawyer files a case and a jury returns a $10 billion verdict, that's basically always going to be a win. And if a lawyer files a case and a judge immediately throws it out, that's pretty clearly a loss.
But the vast majority of cases aren't going to be that clear cut. If I get hit by a car and my lawyer negotiates a settlement of $8,000 for me, is that a "win"? What if he wins a jury verdict of $100,000, but the insurance company previously offered to settle for $500,000?
What if a lawyer persuades a jury that the driver was liable but the jury decides I had no damages? Has the lawyer won my case?
If you're looking to assess a lawyer's success, a more useful approach might be to ask the lawyer to point to specific cases that you can evaluate and see what kind of outcomes he or she obtained.

It is possible to find much of this information in states that have statewide efiling systems and allow searches of cases by lawyer. It is cumbersome and it is hard to evaluate how good settlements were, and often only lawyers have access to this database in this way, but it isn't in principle impossible. Lawyers usually disclose every state where they practice, so it isn't hard to know which states have to be searched.

Do any of those states actually allow you to search by attorney? I've only had experience with Virginia's, which doesn't have that feature.

It is possible in Colorado and in the federal PACER system. I've never tried to do it in New York State, so I don't know if it is possible there.
